# IOS Swift I can't get my real location from my app. I alway get the Apple Inc address

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, cllocation

I always see the Apple inc as my current location on the map in my application's simulator. Can you help me to fix that?

Comment: You need to show more detail. How could you expect us to help you fix something without that? Also, are you sure - I don't honestly know - that your *simulator* has the *necessary* hardware to do GPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your simulator's location using the debug menu `Debug > Location` and choose a `Custom Location`, `City Run`, `City Bicycle Ride` or `Freeway Drive`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change custom location in simulator settings, or turn off simulating location in Debug->Location menu